# Calculating the n derivative of state space equations

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

I have a nonlinear model ${\bf{\dot x}} = f\left( {\bf{x}} \right) $
which is represented as follows:

$$\begin{array}{l}{{\dot x}_1} = {x_2}\\{{\dot x}_2} = {x_3} - \alpha {x_4}{x_2} + \frac{\alpha }{T}{x_1}\\{{\dot x}_3} = \left( { - \alpha  - \frac{\alpha }{T}} \right){x_2}\\{\dot x_4} =  - \frac{1}{T}{x_4}\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaaceWG4b
% GbaiaadaWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaGccqGH9aqpcaWG4bWaaSbaaSqa
% aiaaikdaaeqaaaGcbaGabmiEayaacaWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaO
% Gaeyypa0JaamiEamaaBaaaleaacaaIZaaabeaakiabgkHiTiabeg7a
% HjaadIhadaWgaaWcbaGaaGinaaqabaGccaWG4bWaaSbaaSqaaiaaik
% daaeqaaOGaey4kaSYaaSaaaeaacqaHXoqyaeaacaWGubaaaiaadIha
% daWgaaWcbaGaaGymaaqabaaakeaaceWG4bGbaiaadaWgaaWcbaGaaG
% 4maaqabaGccqGH9aqpdaqadaqaaiabgkHiTiabeg7aHjabgkHiTmaa
% laaabaGaeqySdegabaGaamivaaaaaiaawIcacaGLPaaacaWG4bWaaS
% baaSqaaiaaikdaaeqaaaGcbaGaamiEamaaBaaaleaacaaI0aaabeaa
% kiabg2da9iabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaadsfaaaGaamiEam
% aaBaaaleaacaaI0aaabeaaaaaa!5F81!
$$

where $\alpha, T$ are constants.
I want to calculate ${{\bf{x}}^{\left( n \right)}} = f\left( {\bf{x}} \right)$.
I am new to Mathematica, so any reference or help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain how discrete steps are obtained from these differential equations. 
 Also, should the left side of the fourth equation be a first derivative?

Comment: Hello, I modified the question, sorry for the unclarity, I am interested in calculating the nth derivative of the system equations.

Comment: This model is linear; you can see this by solving equation 4 as $x_4(t)=Ae^{-t/T}$ and substituting back into equation 2.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to calculate the system state after n steps

To do that, use `OutputResponse`. This gives the output of the system. You decide on how long to look at the output.  Also your system is continuous not discrete.

But to do this, you need to have $u$ added to your equations (the external forcing function). Otherwise the system will not move. (since no initial conditions are given, system assumed at rest at time $t=0$).

Right now you do not have any. Then you can tell Mathematica to solve the system and show the output with some specific input to use for `u`. Like this (notice, added $u$ for first equation. You can change
that)

```
sys={{x2+u,x3-alpha*x4*x2+alpha/T*x1,(-alpha-alpha/T)*x2,-1/T*x4}};
nsys=NonlinearStateSpaceModel[sys,{x1,x2,x3,x4},u]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can move it. Used `UnitStep` for $u$ here. You can change that also.

```
params={T->1,alpha->2};
output=OutputResponse[nsys/.params,UnitStep[t],{t,0,5}];
Plot[output, {t, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"time", "state x"}, 
 BaseStyle -> 12, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Each curve above is the output of each state variable.

**Update**

> I am interested in calculating the derivatives, not getting system
> response

If you want to just take derivatives, then you do not need state control. Just use `D` operator

```
ClearAll[x1, x2, x3, x4, t,n]
sys = {x2[t], x3[t] - alpha*x4[t]*x2[t] + alpha/T*x1[t], (-alpha - alpha/T)*x2[t], -1/T*x4[t]}
```

Now take as many derivatives as you want

```
D[sys, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
D[sys, {t, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
D[sys, {t, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your help.
First point: Yes, the given equations are continuous, because I want to calculate the nth derivative, then I will do the discretization.
Second point: for input, u is constant, that's why I didn't added in the equations,
Third points: I am interested in calculating the derivatives, not getting system response, because I am controlling the system on matlab using NMPC controller

Comment: @coder00 fyi, added just taking derivatives.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that we have $x'=f(x), x^{(n-1)}=F_{n-1}(x)$, then $x^{(n)}=x'.\nabla F_{n-1}=f.\nabla F_{n-1}$, where $\nabla_i=\partial_{x_i}$. therefore, with given `x'=f[x]` we can compute any derivative $x^{(n)}=F_n(x)$ as follows:

```
f = {x[2], 
   x[3] - a x[4] x[2] + a/T x[1], -a (1 + 1/T) x[2], -1/T x[4]};
q[y_] := Sum[f[[i]] D[y, x[i]], {i, 4}];
```

Second derivative

```
d2x=q[f] // Simplify

(*Out[]= {(a x[1])/T + x[3] - a x[2] x[4], 
 a (-x[2] + ((-a x[1] + x[2]) x[4])/T - x[3] x[4] + a x[2] x[4]^2), (
 a (1 + T) (-a x[1] - T x[3] + a T x[2] x[4]))/T^2, x[4]/T^2}*)
```

Third derivative

```
 d3x = q[q[f]] // Simplify

(*Out[]= {a (-x[2] + ((-a x[1] + x[2]) x[4])/T - x[3] x[4] + 
    a x[2] x[4]^2), -((
  a (T^2 x[3] + x[2] x[4] - 2 T x[3] x[4] + 
     a^2 T x[4]^2 (-x[1] + T x[2] x[4]) + 
     a (-2 x[1] x[4] - T^2 x[4] (2 x[2] + x[3] x[4]) + 
        T (x[1] + 3 x[2] x[4]^2))))/T^2), -((
  a^2 (1 + T) ((-a x[1] + x[2]) x[4] - 
     T (x[2] + x[3] x[4] - a x[2] x[4]^2)))/T^2), -(x[4]/T^3)}*)
```

Fourth derivative

```
d4x = q[q[q[f]]] // Simplify

(*Out[]= {-((
  a (T^2 x[3] + x[2] x[4] - 2 T x[3] x[4] + 
     a^2 T x[4]^2 (-x[1] + T x[2] x[4]) + 
     a (-2 x[1] x[4] - T^2 x[4] (2 x[2] + x[3] x[4]) + 
        T (x[1] + 3 x[2] x[4]^2))))/T^2), (1/(T^3))
 a ((x[2] - 3 T x[3]) x[4] + a^3 T^2 x[4]^3 (-x[1] + T x[2] x[4]) + 
    a (-3 x[1] x[4] + 7 T x[2] x[4]^2 + T^3 (x[2] + 2 x[3] x[4]) - 
       T^2 x[4] (4 x[2] + 5 x[3] x[4])) - 
    a^2 T x[4] (5 x[1] x[4] + T^2 x[4] (3 x[2] + x[3] x[4]) - 
       2 T (x[1] + 3 x[2] x[4]^2))), (1/(T^3))
 a^2 (1 + T) (T^2 x[3] + x[2] x[4] - 2 T x[3] x[4] + 
    a^2 T x[4]^2 (-x[1] + T x[2] x[4]) + 
    a (-2 x[1] x[4] - T^2 x[4] (2 x[2] + x[3] x[4]) + 
       T (x[1] + 3 x[2] x[4]^2))), x[4]/T^4}*)
```

Technically we can organize this series with `Table`,`Do` or `NestList`.

Answer (score 3):

The r.h.s and the equations expressed as rules.

```
f = {x2[t], (a x1[t])/T + x3[t] - α x2[t] x4[t], (-(a/T) - α) x2[t], -(x4[t]/T)}
rules = Thread[D[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]}, t] -> f]
```

Take the first derivative of $f$ and substitute the rules to get ${{\bf{x}}^{\left( 2 \right)}}$.

```
D[f, t] /. rules
```

To do the same thing for the third derivative, repeat it for the above result.

```
D[%, t] /. rules
```

This is a [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) operation. To get to any derivative, say 3, do

```
Nest[D[#, t] /. rules &, f, 3-1]
```

$$\left\{\frac{\alpha  \left(\text{x2}(t) \left(\alpha  T
   \text{x4}(t)^2+\text{x4}(t)-T\right)-\text{x4}(t) (a \text{x1}(t)+T
   \text{x3}(t))\right)}{T},\frac{\alpha  \left(a \text{x1}(t) (\text{x4}(t) (\alpha  T
   \text{x4}(t)+2)-T)-\text{x2}(t) \text{x4}(t) \left(\alpha  T \text{x4}(t) (\alpha  T
   \text{x4}(t)+3)-2 \alpha  T^2+1\right)+T \text{x3}(t) (\text{x4}(t) (\alpha  T
   \text{x4}(t)+2)-T)\right)}{T^2},\frac{\alpha  (a+\alpha  T) \left(\text{x4}(t) (a
   \text{x1}(t)+T \text{x3}(t))-\text{x2}(t) \left(\alpha  T
   \text{x4}(t)^2+\text{x4}(t)-T\right)\right)}{T^2},-\frac{\text{x4}(t)}{T^3}\right\}$$

If you need the intermediate results use [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html).

These will give any derivative as a function of the original states ${{\bf{x}}^{\left( n \right)}}=g\left(\bf{x}\right)$. If the system has inputs, the derivatives of these inputs will appear in $g$.